# It is possible to use chrome / chromium webview in Cordova application for Windows 8/8.1/10 Store App?

Tags: windows, cordova, webview, cordova-plugins

I want to build a cross platform application in Apache Cordova that uses a Chromium-based Webview component for Windows Store Apps.

Similar to Crosswalk https://github.com/crosswalk-project/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

It's possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Store apps cannot use Chrome and must use the default browser shipping with windows [(you can't even put a none-Edge browser into the windows store)](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-has-effectively-banned-third-party-browsers-from-the-windows-store/).  I guess the good news is that if you are patient, Blink (which is the rendering engine Chrome is based upon) is becoming the default rendering engine for Edge next year.  BTW crosswalk is also dead, as Chrome is now the rendering engine for all modern Android phones..

Edit from 2020...  Since Slack and other Electron apps are in the store and since Cordova now supports Electron - you might want to go with Electron instead of creating a Windows Store app.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the rendering engine for Windows 8.1 / 10 Cordova apps isn't even Edge - it's Internet Explorer 11, which still comes with Windows 10. I'm not sure how a Cordova app would handle this if the user uninstalls IE11 via their programs and features settings.

Comment: @PeterCullen good point about it being IE 11 for rendering.  Since IE11 is still used for FileExplorer rendering and such I think that removing it from features and settings hides the program but the underlying renderer is still there.